# How to check if the Thrift is working on HBase version 2.5 and How to indicate if Thrift 1 or Thrift 2 is installed?

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, happybase

I am totaly new for Big Data world, would you please provide the command to indicate the version of Thrift on ubuntu.

I am using HappyBase to interact with a remote HBase tables using python

> import happybase
> connection = happybase.Connection(host='192.168.232.133', port=9000, autoconnect=True)

But I got below Error, as stated in some article that HappyBase is not working with Thrift2, so in this case what is the solution?
Is it doable to configure from HBase side to disabel Thrift2 and enable Thrift 1, if yes, please share the steps.

> thriftpy2.transport.base.TTransportException:
> TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')

Note: the OS is Ubuntu 22.04, installed Hadoop version 3.3.6 and hadoop version 2.5.7